SwiftData SortDescriptor: Sort on Count of a Relationship Property?
Context
Using Swift 6 and Xcode 16, consider these truncated SwiftData model classes with a many-to-many relationship between tags and employees:
@Model
final class Employee
{
    var tags: [Tag]
}



@Model
final class Tag
{
    var name: String
    @Relationship (inverse: \Employee.tags) var employees: [Employee]
}

Question:
I want to fetch the top five most-used Tag objects. I attempted to do that like this:
var fd = FetchDescriptor<Tag>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\employees.count, order: .reverse)]
fd.fetchLimit = 5

let tags: [Tags]? = try? modelContext.fetch(fd)

This compiles correctly, but crashes at runtime with this:
Fatal Error: Couldn't find \Tag.employees.count on Tag with fields ... [truncated]

Does SwiftData not have the ability to sort by counts of relationships? Since I can't query on computed properties, is my only option to add a numberOfUses stored property on Tag and then manually keep that up-to-date?
(Can't use didSet on the employees property because Tag is decorated @Model and Swift is a giant mess of non-interoperable parts nowadays, so keeping the count manually updated would be fragile. Is there a better, idiomatic way to sort by count in SwiftData?)
Workaround:
Because I expect the number of Tag objects in the database to never exceed a few hundred (and I'm on macOS, which is not resource-constrained), I can simply fetch all Tag objects, sort them myself, and then take the top five. But suppose there were millions of these objects.
I've been away from Core Data for years, but as I recall it didn't play nicely with @count in NSSortDescriptor either and required this same workaround. I take it nobody at Apple decided to bring Core Data into the 2020's with the SwiftData wrapper. (Maybe Apple will finally buy Realm!)

You could try adding a derived attribute to your Tag model, eg var employeesCount: Int { employees.count } and use that in the SortDescriptor.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Computed properties are not supported for fetching or sorting from SwiftData.

ha, ok my bad, it was just a thought.

This is not supported in SwiftData and I am not sure it can be done even in sql in an efficient manner. You need to do it yourself as you mentioned
